# How do i configure Normalize with Cygwin?

Tags: bash, windows-10, cygwin, make, configure

[Normalize](http://normalize.nongnu.org/) is a 32-bit windows program installed with Cygwin, according to the [Readme](http://normalize.nongnu.org/README.html).

I run 64 bit windows 10. Some files referenced by the Readme are missing, like "Install".

I'm instructed to open a bash shell, CD to where i extracted the zip and:

`Type "./configure", then "make", then "make install".`

This returns `no such file or directory`. I've installed a range of Make and Config applications (both under the Dlevel category) through Cygwin, but i get the same error.

I see no config file in the zip, even as a hidden file.

Comment: We will need specific information on the reason you believe this can't "configure" or "make" the program if you want help because there isn't a technical reason you can't.  Windows 10 64-bit supports all 32-bit programs.

Comment: The readme instructs me to open a bash shell, cd to where i extracted the zip and: `Type "./configure", then "make", then "make install"`. Bash claims there's no such file or directory, and i can't see either in the zip.

Comment: What sort of errors? configure and make are applications you need to have installed to build things.

Comment: geek, see my previous comment

Comment: @ErljaJkdf. - Please update your question to include the relevant information.

Comment: Where can i install the configure application? I've got make, and thanks

Comment: use the Cygwin package manager to install both. Run cygwin's setup.exe again and when you get to the packages screen make sure you select `make` this time.

Comment: I've installed the Dlevel category, which possesses config files for "package compiling utilities". Still `file or directory not found`

Comment: You were downloading the wrong file. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I see no configure file in the zip, even as a hidden file.

You don't need to build it.

> normalize 0.7.7 for Windows (linked statically with MAD and Audiofile)

Download http://savannah.nongnu.org/download/normalize/normalize-0.7.7-win32.zip and extract the files.

`normalize-0.7.7-win32.zip` contains `normalize.exe` already built:

[image]

> NOTES ON THE WIN32 BINARY
>
> - I can provide very little support for the windows platform, as I    don't use it myself, except to compile this binary every now and
>     then.
> - This binary was compiled using MinGW32, http://www.mingw.org/ .
> - The audiofile and mad libraries have been compiled statically into    the binary.
> - The source code is not included in this package, but is available    at http://www.nongnu.org/normalize/ .  The source code for the
>     audiofile and mad libraries are also available from their
>     respective home pages, which are linked to from the normalize page.
>     Just to be sure that this package is in compliance with the GPL, I
>     will also provide the source to audiofile and mad upon request.
> - See the file README for general information on normalize.

Source README.win32 from http://savannah.nongnu.org/download/normalize/normalize-0.7.7-win32.zip

---

#### But I really want to build it myself.

Download http://savannah.nongnu.org/download/normalize/normalize-0.7.7.tar.gz and extract the files.

`0.7.7.tar.gz` contains the source code (including the 'missing' `INSTALL` file):

[image]

---

#### For some reason the exe closes as soon as I open it?

It's a command line program so you shouldn't run it from `explorer`.

Run it from a `cmd` prompt or from a Cygwin Terminal.

Now you can give the program input file(s) and any required command line options.

Comment: Ah. For some reason the exe closes as soon as i open it?

Comment: It should give you `Usage: normalize.exe [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Try normalize.exe --help for more information.`.  Are you running it from a command line or from explorer? It's a command line program. Either run from a `cmd` shell or from a Cygwin Terminal.